# How to create a method that works with any reference type?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to turn the following method into a generic method that works with any reference type:

```
public string CheckNull(string value, string defaultvalue)
{ 
    return (value == null) ? defaultvalue : value; 
}
```

Comment: Why would you need to? The caller can just use `someValue ?? defaultValue` - built in.

Comment: What C# operator I can use that makes the method unnecessary ?

Comment: @CyberTramp look at my answer, and RV1987's. It's the null-coalescing operator.

Comment: @CyberTramp the one I used in my comment?

Comment: @CyberTramp Accept some answers that helps your and vote for here, like this one here !

Answer (score 5):

You can use something like:

```
public T CheckNull<T> (T value, T defaultValue)
    where T : class
{
    return value ?? defaultValue;
}
```

Although, it usually makes sense to just use the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) directly instead of wrapping it in a method.

**Edit**

In reference to your comment, you are writing more code to do something that is built into the framework already.

```
public void Foo (Bar bar)
{
    var myBaz = bar.Baz ?? new Baz ();
}
```

Which would do the same thing as all that extra code I have above:

```
public void Foo (Bar bar)
{
    var myBaz = CheckNull (bar.Baz, new Baz ());
}
```

More typing with no return.

Answer (score 0):

Look for [Null Coalescing Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) instead of generic function.